# Should I avoid using the `postgres` database for application data?

Tags: postgresql

The [Cloud SQL documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/create-manage-databases) says:

> Don't use the `postgres` database for your application's data.

This of course might be something GCP-specific (although I bet it's not). Anyways, is there any specific reason I should not use this db on GCP, AWS or any dedicated/unmanaged/physical server? This sounds like a just-in-case advice.

Comment: I don't know how cloud services handle the `postgres` database. In normal PostgreSQL, there is no problem with putting application data into `postgres`. However, it is tradition not to do it. The database is normally left empty and just used for administrative purposes, like a database to connect to so that you can `CREATE DATABASE`. That's what it was invented for in [commit 6f7fc0bade](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commit;h=6f7fc0badef55b376f408bd318a8065fd2edf266). See the commit message.

Answer (score 1):

> This of course might be something GCP-specific (although I bet it's not)

How often do you bet like this?

When you (steer your own boat | maintain your own server), you are responsible for its, and its (passengers | data), well-being. When you (board someone else's boat | put your data on someone else's server), you lose control over what happens, and you ignore the (captain's | provider's) suggestions at your peril.

So, yeah, go ahead and put your data in the `postgres` database, but if it goes missing one day, you'll only have yourself to blame (in either case).

Comment: First, my bet was that the advice applies only to GCP instances because I couldn't find the corresponding information on PostgreSQL in general. Second, when someone's telling me to do something without providing a reason or at least telling me about the risks I'm facing (e.g. cross yourself before boarding a boat), and the risks are not obvious, I ignore it because the information is useless. I have no way to know what are the risks and whether they apply to me. Moreover it drops a shadow on the captain himself, is he even sane? Or on the boat, will it sink without a prayer?...

Comment: ...Think Comin' in on a Wing and a Prayer. But again, it's not only about GCP, it's also about physical servers running PostgreSQL servers. And yeah, I'm kind of sick of just-in-case programming where people write 10 times more code just in case which has no effect save for making it more complex than it should be. And yes, it might be something GCP-specific after all. To err is human.